# Вставить скопированные ячейки из Excel в ячейки QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, excel, qtablewidget, qclipboard

Через *QT Designer* создал таблицу, условно говоря на **`3`**х**`3`** ячеек. 
Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы данные в таблицу я переносил из того же *Excel* сразу из нескольких ячеек?

В *Excel* **`3`** ячейки скопировал и в **`3`** ячейки вставил - просто копипастить из *Excel* чтобы было удобно. А потом уже думаю вытаскивать полученные данные, из того что введено пользователем и вносить эти данные в фильтр для поиска (полученные данные будут своеобразным фильтром для поиска).

Код вот такой:

````
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 80))  
        self.setWindowTitle("Работа с QTableWidget")  
        central_widget = QWidget(self)  
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)  

        grid_layout = QGridLayout()  
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)  

        table = QTableWidget(self)  
        table.setColumnCount(3)  
        table.setRowCount(3)  

        
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["1","2","3"])

        
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setToolTip("столбик 1 ")
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setToolTip("столбик 2 ")
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setToolTip("столбик 3 ")

        
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)

        
        table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("введи сюда 1"))
        table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("введи сюда 2"))
        table.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem("введи сюда 3"))

        
        table.resizeColumnsToContents()

        grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())```
````

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60715462/how-to-copy-and-paste-multiple-cells-in-qtablewidget-in-pyqt5

тут думаю есть ответ на ваш вопрос. Посмотрите внимательно тут

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно перехватить событие клавиатуры <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,
переопределив метод `keyPressEvent` и обработав данные буфера обмена вручную.

Вы можете использовать `QClipboard` и `QMimeData` для получения данных **`Excel`** из буфера обмена.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 

        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(3, 3, self.centralwidget)
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        
        self.clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_V and event.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
            # Вручную обрабатывать данные буфера обмена и вставлять 
            # их в таблицу, начиная с выбранного tableitem

            mime_data = self.clipboard.mimeData()
            #print(* mime_data.formats(), sep='\n') 

            data = mime_data.data('application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="Csv"')
            #                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            # Проверьте, содержит ли буфер обмена данные Excel.
            #  vvvv
            if data:
                # преобразовать из QByteArray в строку
                data = data.data().decode()                 

                list_item = data.split('\r')[0]
                list_item = list_item.split(';')
                #print(f'list_item = {list_item}') 
                
                selectedIndexes = self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes()   
                if selectedIndexes:
                    row = selectedIndexes[0].row()
                    column = selectedIndexes[0].column()
                    #print(f'row = {row}, column = {column}')
                    
                    rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
                    columns = self.tableWidget.columnCount()  
                    #print(f'rows = {rows}, columns = {columns}')
                    
                    # проанализируйте данные и вставьте их в таблицу.
                    for item in list_item:
                        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem(item))
                        column += 1
                        if column >= columns:
                            break
                else:   
                    msg = QMessageBox.information(
                        self, 
                        'Внимание', 
                        'Выберите ячейку, начиная с которой будите вставлять данные.'
                    ) 
            return
        super(MainWindow, self).keyPressEvent(event)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(520, 320)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]